# Ajax XMLHttpRequest invokes servlet doFilter or not

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I'm trying an ajax call from jsp page like below,

```
 <head>
    <script>
        function loadXMLDoc() {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

    </body>
```

Here for the first time servlet filter is called but during ajax calls i can't see doFilter called.

url-mapping for filter is mapped for all incoming requests to server as *.

Why Servlet filter is not invoked for Ajax calls here?

Comment: xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

try writing response text from inside ready state change

Answer (score 1):

```
 <head>
    <script>
        function loadXMLDoc() {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
            xmlhttp.send();

        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

    </body>
```

use the `onreadystatechange` function.